# Difference display in web browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I am designing a simple html page in asp. I haven't any problems in Mozilla and Google Chrome, but in IE everything displays wrong!!!

I use a `div` tag into another `div` with a simple `width`, `margin` and `padding`.

This page address is: [Wrong display in IE](http://vastac.com)

What must I do to fix the display problem in IE (6, 7, 8)?

Comment: Which IE? 5,6,7,8,9,10?

Comment: and please put codes here to help us help you.

Comment: What exactly is the display problem? Can you prove a screenshot alongside the specific html/css - it's probably simple to fix, but we need more info.

Comment: You are asking people here to help you fix your site without explaining what exactly is wrong or showing any efforts of your own; that's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 2):

A common problem of some version of IE is that it consider it's `box-sizing` always as `padding-box`. This means that the padding you apply to an element will be added to the width and the border, so if you have a element with a width of `200px`, `10px` of padding and `1px` of border the total width will be `202px` in almost all browsers and `222px` in IE.

There are many fixes available for this problem.

- You can link another CSS only if the browser is IE (there are special [conditional tags](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) available).
- You can specify `box-sizing: padding-box` and use the same CSS for everything.
- You can use some CSS [hacks](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/).

Comment: You should mention that with recent versions of IE, the box-sixing thing is only a problem in quirks mode. So if the OP would slap a DOCTYPE on the site, the problems might just go away.

Comment: @Mr: Well, what if the user doesn't have a "recent version of IE" ?

Comment: That's not my point. My point it that the box-sizing problem is most likely caused by not using a proper DOCTYPE declaration. Besides, people who still have ancient IE versions have bigger problems than just websites displaying badly.

Answer (score -1):

Viewing in IE has always been a horror movie for me. It doesn't support many features, mainly of CSS. Go to [this awesome website](http://www.w3schools.com/) and see what pieces of your styling isn't supported in IE and please put your code over here so we can see it. Thankfully there is a thing called IE comments in HTML, using which you can say that these pieces of code are specially for IE and these need to be removed while showing in IE. Using those you can put link to a CSS stylesheet for IE and a link for the actual stylesheet.

Comment: -1 for a general, unhelpful link to the [worstest site in the universe](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @deceze I hope it was meant as sarcasm.

Comment: @deceze don't say that. I learned most of the things from there. It has got detailed info about each and every web language it teaches. If you think it is bad, just even make 0.1% of the website that is. It's so popular that when you type the name of a web language on google, it is the first link. It's web programming wikipedia and you're showing us sites like 'w3fools' for fools!

Comment: @Ishpreet Uhm, did you *read* what w3fools has to say about w3schools *and alternative resources*?

Comment: @deceze yeah, that's ok, but still i'm with w3schools. That's your opinion and this is mine.

Comment: @deceze W3Fools is much too opinionated to be taken seriously. If anything, they make things worse by causing people to get curious and check W3Schools out.